# How to display in View the Function Import Complex Result or Stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am looking for help with MVC and the Entity Framework. I have imported a stored procedure into my Entity Framework and it returns a Collection of Complex Name_Results.

How do I go about calling the complex result and tying it to the View page? Using a normal table imported model, 
I could iterate through the page and reference the model with

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ImportedTableName>
```

but when I say

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ComplexName_Result>
```

I get an error along the lines of

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.ImportedTableName]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.ComplexName_Result]'.
```

Any advice? Thank you ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the correct model type to the view. Since your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<Project.Models.ComplexName_Result>` that's what you should pass to it from your controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    IEnumerable<Project.Models.ComplexName_Result> model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Another solution that I used was  reverting back to my old @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ImportedTableName>. The change I made was on the ActionResult MyPage() page. I changed the script around by declaring a variable and calling my stored procedure from there. Then I returned that variable as a list. Sort of like this: var _updatedlist = db.importedstoredprocedure(); return View(_updatedlist.ToList()); Hope that helps anyone else out there.